# Xml.nodeValue causes "Bad node type" error

Tags: xml, exception, haxe, xmlnode, neko

```haxe
class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function new() 
    {
        super();

        try 
        {
            var xml:Xml = Xml.parse("<count>6</count>");

            trace(xml.nodeType);

            for (x in xml.elementsNamed("count"))
            {
                trace(x.nodeName);
                trace(x.nodeType);
                trace(x.nodeValue);
            }
        } 
        catch (err:Dynamic) 
        {
            trace(err);
            Sys.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

> Main.hx:23: 6
>
> Main.hx:27: count
>
> Main.hx:28: 0
>
> Main.hx:34: Bad node type, unexpected 0

I can't fully understand the principle of operation of `nodeValue` property. Because of that, I can't solve my problem. Any help here?

P.S. My configuration is: Haxe + OpenFL targeting Neko.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elementsNamed()` returns nodes of type `XmlType.Element`, and the [docs for `nodeValue`](https://api.haxe.org/Xml.html#nodeValue) explicitly state:

> Returns the node value. Only works if the Xml node **is not an Element** or a Document.

So `nodeValue` will work for all other possible [`XmlType`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/3.4.4/std/Xml.hx) values. In your case, the value you want to retrieve is stored in a `XmlType.PCData` node, and you can access it using [`firstChild()`](https://api.haxe.org/Xml.html#firstChild):

```haxe
for (x in xml.elementsNamed("count"))
{
    trace(x.firstChild().nodeType); // 1 - XmlType.PCData
    trace(x.firstChild().nodeValue); // 6
}
```

The full structure of `<count>6</count>` looks like this:

```haxe
[XmlType.Document] -> [XmlType.Element <count>] -> [XmlType.PCData 6]
```